# How do I train my carpenty skill?

Tags: rpg-mo

I just started playing rpg mo beta and I can't figure out how to even begin with my carpentry skill. Most of my other skills are already between level 20 and 30. Where should one start with carpentry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with carpentry, visit farmer at Dorpat. He will sell you the House Deed. After that click on the House Deed and you get teleported to your house. Inside your house you will see a new house icon. It gives access to item building(carpentry) and removing.

To create items click on Open Build Menu. You can see items only what you can build at current carpentry level.

Items will be taken from your chest and placed there. So no need to carry them with you when you want to build something. But you can sell and trade house items on market also.